# MongoDB: Updating documents using current fields value

Tags: mongodb

I have mongodb "Mydb" with collection "users".

```
export let User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

let UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      phone           : {
        type    : String,
        validate: {
```

Now I want to update field "phone" replacing whitespaces (for example). I try to use following:

```
User.update({}, {$set : {'phone': //here is my problem}},
{multi: true, upsert:false}, () => next());
```

How can I get current "phone" value to replace it? (I use mongoose-migrate)

As I said I try to use mongoose-migration module, so I've created new migration file like this:

```
    'use strict'
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
import { User, dbConnection } from '../db/index'

export function up(next) {
User.update({}, {$set : {'phone': this.phone}}, {multi: true, upsert:false}, () => next());
}


export function down(next) {
    next();
}
```

where User:

```
export let User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Comment: where is your `update` call happening? I mean, at what point you update the phone variable. Is it inside your `model` only?

Comment: Use schema method when updating a record.

Comment: What's the underlying MongoDB version?

Comment: In my case this.phones is null, but if I use something like "asdqdq" its correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the phone field for all the documents in the collection from Mongoose, use the **[`Bulk()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/)** API which offers efficient updates especially when you updating a large collection where using a loop to update each document has performance drawbacks.

In order to use the underlying bulk operations API, you should access it via the `.collection` property from the mongoose model. Before using the API, wait for mongoose to successfully connect to the db since Mongoose doesn't really support the **[`"initializeOrderedBulkOp()"`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp/#db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp)** function at the moment as it doesn't work with mongoose's internal buffering system.

The following example works for MongoDB `>= 2.6 and < 3.2` since support for **[`Bulk()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#bulk)** operations is deprecated in version 3.2:

```
mongoose.connection.on("open", (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;  
    let bulkUpdateOps = User.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();    
    let counter = 0;

    User.find({}).lean().exec((err, users) => {
        if (err) throw err;             
        users.forEach((user) => {
            // computations
            let newPhone = user.phone.replace(/\s/g, '');
            counter++;

            bulkUpdateOps.find({ "_id": user._id }).updateOne({
                "$set": { "phone": newPhone }
            });

            if (counter % 500 == 0 ) {
                bulkUpdateOps.execute((err, result) => {
                    if (err) throw err;  
                    bulkUpdateOps = User.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
                    console.log(result);
                });
            }       
        }); 

        if (counter % 500 != 0 ) {            
            bulkUpdateOps.execute((err, result) => {
                if (err) throw err;  
                console.log(result);
            });         
        }       
    });
})
```

---

For Mongoose versions `>=4.3.0` which support `MongoDB Server 3.2.x`, 
you can use **[`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite)** for updates. The following example shows how you can go about this:

```
User.find({}).lean().exec((err, users) => {
    if (err) throw err;  
    let bulkUpdateCallback = (err, r) => {
        console.log(r.matchedCount);
        console.log(r.modifiedCount);
    };
    let bulkUpdateOps = [];

    // Initialise the bulk operations array
    users.forEach((doc) => { 
        let newPhone = user.phone.replace(/\s/g, '');
        bulkUpdateOps.push({ 
            "updateOne": {
                "filter": { "_id": user._id },
                "update": { "$set": newPhone }
            }
        });         
        if (bulkUpdateOps.length == 1000) {
            User.collection.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps, bulkUpdateCallback);
            bulkUpdateOps = [];
        }
    });     
    if (bulkUpdateOps.length > 0) { 
        User.collection.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps, bulkUpdateCallback); 
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update inside your model, using `Schema.Methods`.

use `this.phone` to access that document's `phone` field.

```
User.update({}, {$set : {'phone': this.phone}},
{multi: true, upsert:false}, () => next());
//using this.phone, access phone variable and change to whatever you need to set in update process.
```

Comment: In my case this.phones is null, but if I use something like "asdqdq" its correct

Comment: if your `phone` field is not set, it will give you `null`. If there is something already there, you can use that value of `phone` . BTW is your issue solved?

Comment: unfortunately no. In my case $set : {'phone': this.phone} replace current value with null

Comment: is your update not happening in your `User` model? Is it defined in `UserSchema.methods` or not? If not, that will give `null`